# Angular: custom CSS inside child ngTemplateOutlet

Tags: css, angular, shadow-dom, ng-template

I'm trying to find out how to set custom styles to be applied inside an ngTemplateOutlet in Angular. I have two components, a parent and a child, and I pass a template from the parent to the child, which is then printed using an ngTemplateOutlet. What I'd like to do is to render the templates using both the parent and child's styles, not just one or the other.

Here's what my parent component's HTML looks like:

```
<child-component [template]="myTemplate">
  <ng-template #myTemplate>
    <p class="paragraph">Hello</p>
  </ng-template>
</child-component>
```

CSS:

```
.paragraph { color: red; }
```

And the child:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplate"></ng-container>
```

CSS:

```
.paragraph { font-weight: bold; }
```

What I would want to happen is to see "Hello" with red background and in bold letters, but Angular's shadow DOM encapsulation is forcing the template to ignore the child's styles.

I am aware that I can solve this by removing DOM encapsulation, but that is not an option as I want to avoid adding CSS classes to the global namespace. So I wonder if there's a way to cleanly achieve the desirect effect in Angular.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
::ng-deep{
 .paragraph { font-weight: bold; }
}
```

Comment: That was amazingly simple and fast. Thank you very much!

Comment: @unpollito Most welcome!!! please accept this answer if it works for you:)

Comment: I will. StackOverflow just forces me to wait for 15 minutes before I can accept it. :)

Comment: It is [recommended](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) to use `::ng-deep` instead of `/deep/`.

Comment: @VikasJadhav From your link: "The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the tools."

Comment: Currently there's no alternative right now, so we should all continue to use it, because it's practical.

Comment: @VikasJadhav - Yes, but Angular recommends using `::ng-deep`.

Comment: @connorsFn agree will update my answer.. thank you:)

Comment: @unpollito Do you have any suggestions what should we do unstead of `::ng-deep` using?